# How to avoid background image tile when browser window resizes

Tags: html, css

I used an actual image for the background-image inside `body` tags then fixed it to have an example of the [actual site](http://goo.gl/zH1KM)

When I view on a large screen the background image tiles like this [image]

How can I make it in such a way that the image does not tile and remains a 'single' that was shown in the actual website.

The **CSS** I'm using is below

```
body {
margin:0; padding:0;
background: url(../images/new.jpg) fixed #A8BFAD;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the image to remain actual size:

```
body {
        background: url(../images/new.jpg) fixed #A8BFAD no-repeat;
    }
```

If you want the image to fill the screen:

```
body {
    background: url(../images/new.jpg) fixed #A8BFAD;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this answer gives you two great solutions, one of which you didn't even know you wanted.

Comment: @dkroy I never knew about `background-size: cover;` and it was exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Add `background-repeat:no-repeat;` to `body` in your CSS

```
body {
  margin:0; 
  padding:0;
  background: url(../images/new.jpg) fixed #A8BFAD;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```